# Group generated by several vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-fields

I have two (or more) smooth and integrable vector fields $v,w$ on a smooth manifold $M$. Each generates a flow map $\Phi_v$,$\Phi_w$ that forms a single parameter Lie group of diffeomorphisms. Let's call these groups $G_v$ and $G_w$

If we assume that $v$ and $w$ **commute** ($[v,w]=0$) and are linearly independent as tangent vectors on all points of $M$, then the collection of all flows generated by linear combinations of $v$ and $w$ should also be a Lie group of diffeomorphisms, this time of dimension two.

My question is, can this compound Lie group $G_{v,w}$ be constructed just from the Lie groups $G_v$ and $G_w$? I didn't find any way to do that using standard products, but I might be looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: I'm not convinced $G_{v,w}$ is a 2 dimensional Lie group if you don't assume the vector fields commute. Or at least something akin to the span of $v,w$ being a Lie subalgebra of the vector fields on $M$.

Comment: You might be right, I may have made a mistake when checking for the group axioms to hold. Can you see where it fails?

Comment: It's just a vague intuition at the beginning: if $v,w$ fail to commute very badly, you can sometimes, with iterated commutators, generate enough vector fields such that at a point they generate the whole tangent space. Since the in local coordinates the flow of a bracket is at first order equal to the commutator of the flows, $$\Phi_{w}^{-t}\Phi_{v}^{-t}\Phi_{w}^{t}\Phi_{v}^{t}(m)=\pm[v,w]_mt^2+o(t^2)$$ (there might be a constant involved, like $\frac12t^2$, you could potentially move in all $n$ directions of the manifold. But you'd expect the natural map $G_{v,w}\times M\to M$ to span a\dots

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problem. I'll give it more thought. I'll change the question to include commutativity of the vector fields. Or would that make the answer trivial?

Comment: surface when restricted to a small neighborhood of $\mathrm{id}$. A better reason why, is that the inclusion $G_{v,w}\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ ought to be a morphism of Lie groups in an appropriate sense, with tangent mapping  $$T_{\mathrm{id}}G_{v,w}\to T_{\mathrm{id}}\mathrm{Diff}(M)=\mathcal{X}(M)$$ sending the tangent vector to the curve $\lbrace\Phi_v^t\rbrace_{t\in\Bbb R}$ at $t=0$ to $v$, and $\lbrace\Phi_w^t\rbrace_{t\in\Bbb R}$ at $t=0$ to $w$. This must be a Lie algebra morphism, and so the span of $v,w$ must be a Lie subalgebra of the vector fields on $M$.

Comment: I think the reasonable requirement is that $v,w$ should span a Lie subalgebra of the vector fields on $M$, that is, there must exist real numbers $\lambda,\mu$ with $[v,w]=\lambda v+\mu w$. Then your idea is likely to be correct, and I'm not even sure you need the hypothesis according to which they are linearly independent at every point.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat, thank you very much. I will restrict myself to the simpler case of $[v,w]=0$, as what I'm really interested in is the construction of $G_{v,w}$. I think I will be able to extrapolate from there.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat, you're probably right that point-wise linear independence is not necessary and global independence of v and w would be sufficient. I tried to simplify the problem and this seemed to be a sensible assumption.